# Unhandled Exception that does not throw or get caught in visual studio

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I created an asp.net mvc 3 application that has a `CustomIdentity`. The only place I used this code is in the global.ascx file here:

```
    protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpCookie authCookie = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
        if (authCookie != null)
        {
            FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
            var identity = new CustomIdentity(authTicket);
            BasicRoleProvider roleProvider = new BasicRoleProvider();
            string[] userRoles = roleProvider.GetRolesForUser(identity.Name);
            var principal = new GenericPrincipal(identity, userRoles);
            Context.User = principal;
        }
    }
```

This code gets executed without error. After authentication, I get this error in the browser:

`Type 'MyProj.Web.ViewModel.CustomIdentity' in assembly 'MyProj.Web, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as serializable.`

No exception in visual studio. Here is how my identity looks:

```
public class CustomIdentity : IIdentity
{
    private System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket;

    public CustomIdentity(System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket)
    {
        this.ticket = ticket;
    }

    public string AuthenticationType
    {
        get { return "Custom"; }
    }

    public bool IsAuthenticated
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public string FriendlyName
    {
        get { return ticket.UserData; }
    }
    public string Name
    {
        get { return ticket.Name; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mark CustomIdentity as serializable.

```
[Serializable]
public class CustomIdentity : IIdentity
{...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `[Serializable]` attribute:

```
[Serializable]
public class CustomIdentity : IIdentity
{
    ...
```

The reason you don't get the exception in Visual Studio is that something else already *handles* it. You can actually ask Visual Studio to stop regardless - this is done via Debug / Exceptions. You could find `SerializationException` in there and tick the "thrown" box.

Comment: If you get the error in the browser the exception is probably unhandled so that won't make a difference. In this case you don't see the exception because serialization is called by the framework with no user code anywhere in the call stack.

Comment: @Tom I'm no expert at ASP, so just out of curiosity. In non-ASP apps the only way to produce any kind of output like that involves catching the exception. Leaving it completely _unhandled_ invariably terminates the process. Is ASP not subject to this? Or do you just mean that it's not handled _in user's code_?

Comment: Ok, technically the asp.net error page is an exception handler. Normally though, unhandled means something that will trigger the AppDomain UnhandledException event (or Application_Error in global.asax), basically any exception that doesn't stop in a normal catch block.